# Download location for apache_beam.io.gcp.gcsio.GcsBufferedReader object

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am pushing video to workers for a cloud dataflow pipeline. I have been advised to use beam directly to manage my objects. I can't understand the best practices for downloading objects. I can see the class

[Apache Beam IO GCP](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/pydoc/0.6.0/apache_beam.io.gcp.html) So one could use it like so:

```
def read_file(element,local_path):
  with beam.io.gcp.gcsio.GcsIO().open(element, 'r') as f:
```

Where element is the gcs path read from a previous beam step.

Checking out the available methods, downloader looks like.

```
f.downloader
Download with 57507840/57507840 bytes transferred from url https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/api-project-773889352370-testing/o/Clips%2F00011.MTS?generation=1493431837327161&alt=media
```

This message makes it seem like it has been downloaded, it has the right file size (57mb). But where does it go? I would like to pass a variable (local_path), so that subsequent process can handle the object. The class doesn't seem accept a path destination, its not in current working directory, /tmp/ or downloads folder. I'm testing locally on OSX before I deploy.

Am I using this tool correctly? I know that streaming video bytes may be preferable for large videos, we'll get to that once I understand basic functions. I'll open a separate question for streaming into memory (named [pipe](http://answers.opencv.org/question/164822/read-a-named-pipe-in-opencv/)?) to be read by opencv.

Comment: While I'll keep this question open, its worth noting that gsutil is installed automatically in the dataflow worker environment, so it was easiest just use subprocess to all gsutil commands from shell to download objects. See here https://github.com/bw4sz/DeepMeerkat/blob/master/run_clouddataflow.py